# How can I get `emacs --daemon` to load the Spacemacs configuration?

Tags: spacemacs, emacsclient, emacs-daemon

I have configured my `~/.emacs` so: It either launches default emacs via the default init.el, or runs the Spacemacs `init.el`

I run Spacemacs via a `spacemacs` shell script, `~/bin/spacemacs`

```shell
#!/bin/sh
export USE_SPACEMACS="1";
emacs $1
```

and this is the content of `~/.emacs`

```lisp
(setq use-spacemacs (getenv "USE_SPACEMACS"))
(when (> (length use-spacemacs) 0)
    (setq user-emacs-directory "~/.spacemacs.d/"))   ; defaults to ~/.emacs.d/
(load (expand-file-name "init.el" user-emacs-directory))
```

How can I run `emacs --daemon` with the configuration from the `~/spacemacs.d/init.el`? I may have to adjusted to disable stuff like the `server-start` and other such options.

For the meantime I have settled on starting Spacemacs in background `screen` terminal and running the emacsclient commands in my regular terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just pass `--daemon` to your wrapper script?
2. You should change `emacs $1` to `emacs "$@"`
3. ```
   (setq use-spacemacs (getenv "USE_SPACEMACS"))
   (when (> (length use-spacemacs) 0)
   ```

   could be

   ```
   (when (getenv "USE_SPACEMACS")
   ```

Comment: What is the effect of running `(require 'server) (unless (server-running-p) (server-start)))` in daemon mode? Is running in daemon mode equivalent in having `server-running-p`?

Comment: Yes, that code has no effect when emacs was started as a daemon.